# Two colors in one string

Tags: ruby, user-interface, raspberry-pi, gtk, gtk3

Hi I'm trying to do a GUI code using GTK in Ruby and I'm stuck trying to change the color of a String.

I would like the Welcome to be blue and the @name to be red but I can't seem to figure out a way to get both of them

```
@user = Gtk::Label.new("Welcome #{@name}")
css_user = Gtk::CssProvider.new
css_user.load(data: "label{color: blue;}")
```

If anybody could help I would be really greatful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change a little bit the gtk display

```
@box = Gtk::Box.new(:horizontal, 1)
@welcome = Gtk::Label.new("Welcome ")
@user = Gtk::Label.new(@usuari)
css_user = Gtk::CssProvider.new
css_user.load(data: "label{color: blue;}")
css_welcome = Gtk::CssProvider.new
css_welcome.load(data: "label{color: black;}")
@user.style_context.add_provider(css_user, Gtk::StyleProvider::PRIORITY_USER)
@welcome.style_context.add_provider(css_welcome, Gtk::StyleProvider::PRIORITY_USER)
```

As you can see I created two labels (one for each color) and I placed them inside a Horizontal Box